# Change ReadOnly Input Value on <select> option change

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display the value in a "select > option" in an  based on the location selected from my  tag.

Here is the html:

```
<select name="stateCoord" id="stateCoord" autocomplete="off">
       <option selected="selected">SELECT STATE</option>
       <option value="lg">Lagos</option>
       <option value="abj">Abuja</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="stateCoordInfo" value="" id="stateCoordInfo"  readonly>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#stateCoord option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() == $("#stateCoordInfo").val();
}).attr('selected', true);

$("#stateCoord").live("change", function() {

    $("#stateCoordInfo").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
});
});
```

I'm still getting the hang on javascript so a detailed explanation won't hurt. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of the first call to `filter()`, what are you expecting to do with it?. And, you want to show the selected value in the input?

Comment: @Shidersz I got that off a working jsfiddle but it didn't work forme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I assume correctly, you want this:

**1)** initialization of the select option at document ready, that strange thing the code with `filter()` was trying to do.

**2)** Capture the `change` event on the `select` and show the value of the current selected option on the input. This is what the `live()` (**deprecated**) part was trying to do.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#stateCoord").val("").change();

    $("#stateCoord").change(function()
    {
        $("#stateCoordInfo").val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="stateCoord" id="stateCoord">
  <option value="" selected>SELECT STATE</option>
  <option value="lg">Lagos</option>
  <option value="abj">Abuja</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="stateCoordInfo" value="" id="stateCoordInfo">
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if this is what you need, but I think it should be: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FollowMarco/pjz0ys4m/24/)

Here is the JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#stateCoord").change(function() {
      var value = $("#stateCoord option:selected").text();
      $("#stateCoordInfo").val(value);
  });
});
```

Comment: This didn't work. Even on the fiddle you shared @FrishVerwegen

Comment: @EdwardBella Sorry, rather new to using jsfiddle myself. Updated the code on the fiffle and here

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $("body").on("change","#stateCoord",function() {

     $("#stateCoordInfo").val($(this).find("option:selected").val());

});

   $("#stateCoord").trigger("change");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to update the text shown in the `readonly` text box with the `value` attribute of the selected option from the dropdown.

To do this, you just need to update the `val` of your read-only text box to the `val` of the drop-down whenever `change` event is fired.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#stateCoord').change(function(e) {
    $('#stateCoordInfo').val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="stateCoord" id="stateCoord" autocomplete="off">
       <option selected="selected">SELECT STATE</option>
       <option value="lg">Lagos</option>
       <option value="abj">Abuja</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="stateCoordInfo" value="" id="stateCoordInfo"  readonly>
```